# GWT 2.7 super dev mode does not work with CssResource.style=obf

Tags: gwt

Till GWT 2.5, all the css class were obfuscated by default but in GWT 2.7, while running in super dev mode, it append complete package in class name. I have tried below but it does not work.

<set-configuration-property name="CssResource.style" value="obj"/>

I does not obfuscated css styles rather it prints name like com-google-gwt-user-cellview-client-CellTable-Style-cellTableCell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [on purpose](https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/blob/2.7.0/dev/codeserver/java/com/google/gwt/dev/codeserver/Recompiler.java#L505-L512). There's a comment in the code explaining why:

> ```
>   // CSSResourceGenerator needs to produce stable, unique naming for its input.
>   // Currently on default settings CssResourceGenerator's obfuscation depends on
>   // whole world knowledge and thus will produce collision in obfuscated mode, since in
>   // incremental compiles that information is not available.
> ```

along with a TODO to eventually fix the `CSSResourceGenerator`.

But, if I may ask, what's the problem with non-obfuscated style names?

Comment: Thanks Thomas. We have added some custom css style for celltable and for some other widgets. Initially css name was obfuscated and it was become something like GPBYFDEPC or GPBYFDEPD and based on this we have added css styles like - 

tr.GPBYFDEPC td, tr.GPBYFDEPD td,{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
}

Now since css class is generated as com-google-gwt-user-cellview-client-CellTable-Style-cellTableCell instead of GPBYFDEPD, all the screens look ugly.

Comment: By using the obfuscated name, you're asking for trouble. There are ways to customize the style of celltable et al. taking advantage of CssResource; so why rely on something that brittle as an obfuscated name?