# Super Dev Mode doesn't detect xml file change?

Tags: gwt, gwt-super-dev-mode

Just started using GWT 2.7 Super Dev Mode, I am running CodeServer, not through DevMode.

When I work on designing my app theme, I usually turn on Css pretty print temporarily like this:

```
<set-configuration-property name="CssResource.style" value="pretty"/>
```

In the past, with the traditional DevMode with browser plugin, I just refresh the page and it detects my change and recompiles.

But not so with SDM.  The console shows "skipped compile because no input files have changed".  I know my SDM setup is working because it detects changes in java files.  I also tried restarting SDM CodeServer.

The only thing worked for me is to recompile completely, or add -noincremental to SDM, which is inconvenient for a short css debug session.

**Is it expected that SDM ignores xml file changes?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33821819/gwt-2-7-super-dev-mode-does-not-work-with-cssresource-style-obf) made me realized: GWT 2.7 SDM by default (incremental mode) pretty prints css class name.

So I was kind of asking the wrong question.  The answer is: **it ignores CssResource.style property in xml while in incremental mode**.  But there is no need to set CssResource.style property in the first place in my use case.

I had gotten confused because I was expecting to see this property changing the produced html while running SDM.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ctrl+F5 on the browser to clear cached data?